# Как сделать указать на функцию по другому

Tags: c++

Я пытаюсь сделать указатель на функцию с типом `void` но мой код чет гонит и выдает такую ошибку

```
msvcp140d.amd64.pdb содержит отладочную информацию, необходимую для поиска исходного кода для модуля msvcp140d.dll
```

точнее это даже не ошибка просто он проглатывает первое действия во время выполнения.

Но если я буду устанавливать тип `int` вместо `void` тогда все нормально, но я не понимаю зачем ему тип `int` в указатели на функцию и что не так.

Данный код не факт что вызовет такую же ошибку у вас как у меня, но возможно я не правильно что то делаю и вы это увидите.

```
template <class T1>
void alfa_test(T1& alice) {
  alice++;
  std::cout << alice << " зырим" << "\n" << std::endl;
}

template <class T1>
void beta_test(T1& bob) {
  bob++;
  std::cout << bob << " зырим" << "\n" << std::endl;

}

    template <class T1, class T2>
    tester(T1& mod, T2& wtf, void (*func)(T2&)) {
       // вариант 1
       func(wtf);

       // вариант 2 нужен тип int а не void
       if (func(wtf) != 0)

       mod++;
       std::cout << mod << " зырим" << "\n" << std::endl;       
    }

int mod = 0;
int wtf = 0;

int main() {
  tester(mod, wtf, beta_test);
  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: приведенный кусок не собирается просто из-за синтаксических ошибок, не имеющих отношения к указателям на функцию...

Comment: @user7860670 ну да может где то ошибся я же переписывал под вопрос из своего примера.

Comment: ну так доведите его, чтобы получился [mcve], а то совершенно непонятно, что тут за проблема на самом деле

Comment: @user7860670 проблема в том что почему то первое действие проглатывается и компилятор вызывает ошибку которую я написал в момент дебагера, во время нажатие `f11` когда он выходит из функции `void`
как будто ему необходимо получить `return 0` в конце, что бы этого не было

Comment: может быть можно как то по другому делать указатель на функцию?

Comment: "компилятор вызывает ошибку которую я написал в момент дебагера" - а вас не смущает что "в момент дебагера" процесс компилятора уже давно завершил свою работу? Ну и вообще, пока не будет присутствовать [mcve], говорить тут не о чем.

Comment: @user7860670 да не не смущает в чем проблема, вопрос та про указатели на функцию я бы мог пример даже не вставлять.
разве в примере дело, я думаю дело в void функции и видать указатель странно себя ведет если там нет `return 0` вот мне интересно почему это

Comment: "указатель странно себя ведет если там нет return 0" - и что, предлагаете телепатам без примера догадаться, что у вас там не так себя ведет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы сравниваете возвращаемое значение функции с `0`. У нуля тип `int`, а не `void`, поэтому и требуется `int`.

Ещё надо функции `tester` дать возвращаемый тип. Например, `void`.

Comment: нет вы запутались немного я просто не добавил функцию `int` потому что нет смысла просто тоже самое только вместо `void` пишем `int` и в конце функции `return 0;`

Comment: @chip не понял, в чём я запутался. Ты передаешь указатель на функцию `void beta_test(T1& bob)`, у неё возвращаемый тип `void`. Далее ты её вызываешь и сравниваешь результат с 0 `func(wtf) != 0`, но результат типа `void`, а не `int`

Comment: если вы пишите про вариант 2 где я написал что нужно использовать `int` там все отлично работает, проблема в другом, мне нужно использовать `void` а не `int`

Comment: @chip вопрос в чём тогда? Ты говоришь *"я не понимаю зачем ему тип `int` в указатели на функцию и что не так"*. Я объяснил зачем нужен `int`. Если не нужен `int`, то не сравнивай результат с `int`-ом тогда)

Comment: а где я сравниваю значения функции с `0` тогда?

Comment: @chip `func(wtf) != 0` ну вот, я же написал

Comment: блин ну там же написано что это вариант 2 который рабочий если использовать функции `int` а не `void`
Я его добавил просто как пример.

Comment: @chip да, надо либо убрать это, либо заменить тип на `int`. В чём вопрос тогда остался?

Comment: Вопрос как использовать тип `void` и что бы не было ошибки

Comment: @chip вот https://godbolt.org/z/zT3rsa, закоментировал эту строку + ты ещё функции `tester` забыл тип дать, ошибок нет

Comment: да не суть проблема не в этом )

Comment: @chip использован тип `void`, ошибок нет. В чём теперь проблема?)

Comment: @300bucks проблема в том, что ОП не привел [mcve]... не зачем гадать на кофейной гуще..

Comment: проблема не в примере а в том что вы не знаете почему указатель на `void` это не правильно и так делать не нужно. И у кого это узнать я фиг знает.

Comment: @chip конечно, я это не знаю, потому что это неправда) Указатель на `void` вполне валидная и правильная конструкция, как и указатель на функцию с возвращаемым типом `void`. Короче, правильно говорят, приведите пример, который показывает вашу ошибку. Непонятно, в чём проблема сейчас

Comment: Сейчас попробую еще покопаться, напишу может более точно.

Comment: карочи я понял в чем проблема, ее вызывает этот код в конце функции

`  std::cout << bob << " зырим" << "\n" << std::endl;`

видать так незя делать

Comment: @chip как "так"? Это обычная печать в поток, ничего криминального, любый хелловорлд так делает и ничего :)

Comment: @300bucks "A: Сосед рассказывал, что за ночь 10 раз может! Б: Ну и ты рассказывай!"

Comment: надо завязывать с этими выводами пора использовать принт паходу

Comment: @chip ну в питоне в среднем меньше ошибок будет, да. А с `printf` из C скорее больше